# How to switch tabs in UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that is being presented modally from a RootViewController:

```
stvTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
stvTabBarController.delegate = self;
stvTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stvNavController, scheduleNavController, nil];
stvTabBarController.selectedViewController = stvNavController;

[self presentModalViewController:stvTabBarController animated:YES];
```

How can I switch tabs from stvNavController? I can't do:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
```

because I don't have a reference to the tabBarController in the stvNavController.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of stvNavController's `parentViewController` property—it should be a reference to the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code there are only 2 view controllers under the tab controller.

You are trying to select the fourth one...

Answer (score 0):

1:Add UIApplicaition Extension

```
    extension UIApplication {

/*function will return reference to tabbarcontroller */

func tabbarController() -> UIViewController? {

    guard let vcs = self.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers else { return nil }
    for vc in vcs {
        if  let _ = vc as? TabBarViewController {
            return vc
        }
    }
    return nil
}}
```

2: Get the reference of tabbarcontroller

```
    guard let tabbarController = UIApplication.shared.tabbarController() as? TabBarViewController else { return }
   tabbarController.selectedIndex = 3
```